# Promise.all in Redux action and update state

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, es6-promise

I have two main endpoints; Departments and Employees. Departments endpoint returns only the department id and name. Employees endpoint return the employee id and department id. So if I want to get employee details such as first name last name, etc. I need to add employee id to Employees endpoint.

I don't know my logic is correct or not but I think I need to fetch every single employee to render their details on the screen. Because of that, I am trying to use `Promise.all` and then update my state once, **but somehow my state only stores one value** (one employee object) but there are more than 1000 employees.

Here are my steps:
First, make the request to the main Employees endpoint to get all employees (fetchEmployees), then dispatch `fetchEmployeeOneByOne` and in this method make a request inside `Promise.all`, after that finally dispatch `updateEmployees` to set state.

Actions

```
const UPDATE_EMPLOYEES = UPDATE_EMPLOYEES
export const fetchEmployees = () => dispatch => {
  return fetch(EMPLOYEE_MAIN_URL)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
        return res;
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(employees => dispatch(fetchEmployeeOneByOne(employees)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(console.log(error)));
};

export const fetchEmployeeOneByOne= employees => dispatch => {
  Promise.all(
    employees.map(employee =>
      fetch(EMPLOYEE_MAIN_URL + '/' + employee.id)
        .then(res => {
          if (res.ok) {
            return res;
          }
        })
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then(employee => dispatch(updateEmployees(employee)))
        .catch(error => dispatch(console.log(error)))
    )
  );
};

export const updateEmployees = employee => ({
  type: UPDATE_EMPLOYEES,
  payload: employee
});
```

Reducer

```
export const Departments = (
  state = {
    departments: [],
    employees: [],
  },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_EMPLOYEES':
     return { ...state, employees: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With every Promise resolve and reducer cycle you are overwriting the state, so the final result is only one employee.

Instead of assigning to the `employees` field a whole response, just throw it into the `employees` array:

```
case 'UPDATE_EMPLOYEES':
   return { 
      ...state, 
      employees: [...state.employees, action.payload],
   };
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Do you think this is an efficient way? I mean I make more than 1000 requests to the server. (just wondering)

Comment: @TToprak1 It depends what do you really what to achieve. If your API is really fast and reliable, I would keep the single request per employee strategy, since user is going to see the results even just after first request is done, so the change is like immediately. However if you dont care about delay of displaying the data and your API isn't that good quality, you can also make a one, huge request that will do everything on the server-side and will return a single response after everything is done. But it will take some time and if one puzzle fails, the whole maze will fail too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might want to aggregate your employees and then dispatch the action after the `Promise.all` resolves:

```
Promise.all(
  employees.map(employee =>
    fetch(EMPLOYEE_MAIN_URL + '/' + employee.id)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res;
        }
      })
      .then(res=> res.json())
      .catch(error => dispatch(console.log(error)))
  )
).then(employees => dispatch(updateEmployees(employees));
```

Otherwise, if you're just going to dispatch each employees as they come in from your fetch request, there'd really be no reason to use `Promise.all`